# (IBM Worklight) Shared Templates Vs (Import) Existing Project into Workspace

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

In **worklight V6.1.0** and i see a new Project template as **Shared Temlplates** and i cant differentiate the use of the this provided by IBM and the normal import **Existing Project into Workspace** which is provided my the eclipse.

The final result is same and only the vendor and internal process are different

1. In eclipse we export it as the **Generel->archive file** and here we are just making it a template by (**IBM Worklight->Worklight Project Template**).
2. In eclipse we are importing it as **General->Existing Project into Workspace** and here we are just using **Worklight Project->etc** steps.

*if there is any other difference please let me know?*

Answer (score 0):

IBM Worklight Project Template (Shared Template) enable you to accelerate the development of applications by not having to start from scratch. You can use Worklight project templates to provide value added services and you can add elements that are consistent with the look and feel of your brand.
And When we talk about exporting existing project into workspace then we don't have a choice of customization for e.g. certain elements like Company logo, company name etc. but in shared templates we have these capabilities, its totally customizable feature introduced in worklight 6.1
for more information please visit below link
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fstudio_ext_assets%2Fc_wl_project_templates.html

Application Component: 
Application components are reusable libraries that you can add to the applications you develop. An application component can be a client-side library or a server runtime block. Typical libraries might handle basic functions such as login or payments. They can also contain various elements such as non-visual runtime objects, visual components, integration adapters, and user interface screen packages.
For more information please visit below two links

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fstudio_ext_assets%2Fc_application_components.html

Comment: why have you mentioned about application component here and where i can customize company logo,name etc in project templates?

Comment: For detailed information please visit below link :
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc%2Fwhat_s_new%2Fc_wn_faster_app_develop.html